# @txn ignored when features run via test class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, transactions, cucumber

When I run particular features-file (or Scenario or even Scenario Outline) by right-clicking it in IDEA the `@txn` tag is honored, `SpringTransactionHooks#startTransaction` gets called and each Scenario is treated as transacional.

When I run them all via runner class the tag is ignored regardless of whether I put it on Feature level or on Scenario Outline.

My Cucumber runner class, not much to see here:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features")
public class CucumberTest {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `cucumber.api.spring` to glue seems to be the key, as that is the package where class `SpringTransactionHooks` resides.

Keep in mind that by defining `glue` you are overriding its default value, make sure the `glue` now contains your app's classes.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    glue = {"cucumber.api.spring", "my.package.app.classes"},
    features = "src/test/resources/features")
public class CucumberTest {}
```

See the [spring-txn](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/examples/spring-txn) eample.